# Do there exist such sets in Spec(Z[x])

Tags: general-topology, ring-theory

Consider the topological space $(Spec(\mathbb Z[x]), τ )$ where open sets $D_I$ in τ are given as(indexed by ideals
I in $\mathbb Z[x]$):

$$D_I = \{p \in Spec(\mathbb Z[x])|I \not\subset p\}$$

Let $a, b \in Spec(\mathbb Z[x])$. Is it always true that $\exists U, V \in τ$ such that $a \in U, b \in V$ and $a \notin V, b \notin U$?

Comment: How do you identify $a$ and $b$ with elements of the spec? Do you identify the open sets with the corresponding ideals first?

Comment: $a$ and $b$ are in the spec. $U$ and $V$ are in τ.

Comment: That is not what you wrote.

Comment: Sorry, changed it.

Comment: Ok, now the question makes sense. Hint: What happens if $a = \{0\}$?

Comment: $\{0\} \in U$ but what can be said about $V$?

Comment: Well, what open sets contain that ideal? (which closed sets do not?)

Comment: All open sets? (no closed set)

Comment: Well, all non-empty open sets. So how can we have an open set containing $b$ not not this $a$?

Answer (score 1):

The point corresponding to the zero ideal is adherent to the whole spectrum, so it is included in every open set or the spectrum, so the answer to your question is no.

Comment: (More generally, whenever $A$ is a domain, the prime ideal $0$ is dense in ${\rm Spec}\,A$)